# How to convert the return type of the model data from Product entity to ProductViewModel objects using LINQ select?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get product objects to appear on an index page based on the selected category since products belong to categories. The request is as follow:
`products/index/[category ID]`.

The property in the `Category` entity for holding products is:

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

The `Model` I created in the Controller looks like this:

```
var products = (await db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select(c => c.Products).ToListAsync());

return View(products);
```

The Model I have given the `view` is the following type:

@model List>

When making the request: `Product/index/6` after creating products for categories with the ID of '6', I receive a Compilation Error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 15: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)

Full View:

```
@model List<ICollection<ValueVille.Models.ProductViewModel>>
....
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Category Entity Model Class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Product View Model with implicit method to convert between entity and model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name="Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    public string OutputImage { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }

    public static byte[] ConvertToByte(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.Image != null)
        {
            byte[] imageByte = null;
            BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(model.Image.InputStream);
            imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)model.Image.ContentLength);
            return imageByte;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // ViewModel => Model | Implicit type Operator
    public static implicit operator Product(ProductViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var model = new Product
        {
            Id = viewModel.Id,
            Name = viewModel.Name,
            Image = ConvertToByte(viewModel),
            Price = viewModel.Price
        };
        return model;
    }

    // Model => ViewModel | Implicit type Operator
    public static implicit operator ProductViewModel(Product model)
    {
        var viewModel = new ProductViewModel
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Name = model.Name,
            OutputImage = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(model.Image)),
            Price = model.Price
        };
        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that I am not giving the `View` the correct model type and my `Model` created in the `Controller` is not fully accurate. Currently, my model builds a `List<ICollection<Product>>`. I need the form type of `ICollection` to be `ProductViewModel`.

For the Categories which was a lot simpler, I have a table of Categories and the mode return type is simply of type `IEnumerable` and the `Model` created in the `Controller` for that is:

```
var categories = (await db.Categories.ToListAsync()).Select<Category, CategoryViewModel>(x => x);
return View(categories);`
```

`ToListAsync()` grabs the data as `List<Category>` and the `Select<Category, CategoryViewModel>(x => x);` makes a transition between the two types and makes the return type `IEnumerable`. I don't know how to do this for the `Model` for the `products/index` page.

Comment: can you post ProductViewModel POCO?

Comment: Use ```SelectMany```  to return a flat list instead of a List of List. Or in the view use a ```foreach(var item in Model) ...``` and ```DisplayNameFor(model => item.Name)```

Comment: can you mention the `ProductViewModel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select(c => c.Products).ToListAsync()
```

To

```
db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select(c => c.Products.Select(p => new ProductViewModel{ Id = p.Id, map rest of the properties})).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: After I get the right Category by ID, the data I need is the products which arre inside the `ICollection<products> products` property. Then I need to convert each object to ProductViewModel.

Comment: At the moment, Categories are returned, we want the Category's `products` property - Which is of the `ICollection<products>` type.

Comment: I was thinking that I couldn't use Select more than once - clearly wrong. Thank you Ahmar.

Comment: Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `ProductViewModel` have to have

```
ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
```

like

```
public class ProductViewModel{
public string Name { get; set; }
public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

now write the query

```
var products = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == id).Select( new ProductViewModel{  Name=c.Name,Image =c.Image,   Products =c.Products }).ToList();
return products;
```

Now you have to change in the view, Change it to

```
@model List<ValueVille.Models.ProductViewModel>
```

Hope it will wok fine now.  I have seen that you have used collection inside a link, which was causing problem as nesting.

Comment: I did not include `ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}` in the  ProductViewModel since products do not hold other products. Am I still wrong to leave this out?

Comment: Yes, seems so. If this works then don't forget to  thumbs up on the solution. :)